# Is there any methods to encode and decode CRC using natural numbers?

Tags: crc

I know how to encode and decode CRC. For example given the binary message to be encoded was 11010011101100 and the genrator polynomial is 1011
Then the result is:

```
11010011101100 000 <--- input left padded by 3 bits
`1011`               <--- divisor
 01100011101100 000 <--- result
 1011              <--- divisor ...
  00111011101100 000
    1011
    ...
    -----------------
    00000000000000 100 <---remainder (3 bits)
```

and to decode it you use the same technique however replace the 3 zeros with the remainder (100)

however is there a way of using this same method to encode and decode crc codes using normal natural numbers without converting them to binary?

I tried to do some research however, I cant find any method or examples to do it using natural numbers I only seem to find binary examples. Any help please guys?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same exact algorithm. You *are* working with natural numbers. The way they're written is immaterial. "Shift left by three bits" is equivalent to "multiply by 8". "Shift right by one bit" is equivalent to "divide by two, discarding the remainder". "Take the last three bits" is equivalent to "take the remainder from dividing by 8". The bit-xor of two numbers isn't very easy to describe in arithmetical terms though.